# how to insert a diagonal view just like this image

Tags: iphone, xcode

all

I want to insert a view just like diagonal . as shown in this link

http://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/science360-for-ipad/id439928181?mt=8

any idea. b/c I have made straight images vertically I want to do it. vertically but the images shown is in diagonal shape .. as shown in the link...

if you have any tutorial then plz share it to me.

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do that on a web page image? You do that by applying a perspective to the image, a 3D transformation that gives it the illusion of depth. It works in most, but not all, browsers, and the CSS is slightly different depending on the browser.

Here's a good, simple page that explains it: http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/perspective-by-example.html

**UPDATE**
For core animation without using a UIWebView or a browser, you need to use the UIView transforms. See: 
http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/

Comment: thnx for the fast reply Matt, I have this code http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/downloads/list in which it contain the HelloPanorama_0.1_Beta_2.zip  and Paranoma , but it can't run this code..

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, sorry. I updated my answer with a page that shows how to do it using a UIView. I personally use a lot of UIWebView with embedded websites, so that I then get access to all the nice webkit encoding and transforms.

Comment: thnx for the great tutorial now I am applying your logic in my applications.. thnx agaain...

Comment: not solve the problem can it is possible that you integrade this code in iphone and give back to me.. plz